# Format json response asp.net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Hi im currently working on some XSS vulnerabilities on our application basically my goal is to encode all returned object coming from our Web api which is .net core project. im currently looking at some feature or class that i can use to encode all the json response when returning it to requestor?. something like the json formatter that i can implement on my controller

Comment: Did you consider sanitizing the data on input, instead of output? It would be better not to have vulnerable content in your storage / database at all.

Comment: i did consider that but im worried that might be a lot of work since we have a lot of user inputs in our application. so i decided to do it on output. do you think which is better approach?.@YeldarKurmangaliyev

Comment: I would do it on input. ASP.NET already does it and prevents malicious code to be submitted to the application. For example, you can try to enter `<script>alert(1)</script>` in any input like username or password. However, I don't know if it can protect from all sources of XSS. [This MSDN article may also be helpful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cross-site-scripting?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: By the way, this document says "Always encode untrusted input before output, no matter what validation or sanitization has been performed." and it is right - it is better to do it on both input and output.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to only encode output. You should use EF or parametrized queries to protect database from malicious scripts. It will partially protect your json output data. For encoding of output HTML you can use [this library](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer).